# Kotlin Could not find or load main class when deploy on heroku

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I using intellij and wanted to deploy my kotlin project on cloud but got some error when deployed.

> 2022-03-14T14:20:36.467566+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.kotlin.mainKt

can someone help me with this error, this is my gradle config.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.10'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{ url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"

task stage {
    dependsOn build
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    implementation("dev.kord:kord-core:0.7.4")
    implementation('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36')
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation "dev.inmo:krontab:0.7.1"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class' : 'src.main.kotlin.mainKt'
    }
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

and this is my directory structure

src ----> main ----> kotlin ----> main.kt

build.gradle

Comment: The `src` directory is just for _sources_. At deployment, you only have compiled classes.

Comment: should i just go with mainKt @k314159?

Comment: It seems that your main function is defined in a file without a package, so yes, just mainKt. It was previously trying to look for mainKt in a package called src.main.kotlin which of course didn't exist.

Comment: @k314159 thanks for replying, but i still got error Error: Could not find or load main class mainKt and my main function is file without package, should i change it to class?

Comment: Search inside the jar file (e.g. using the `jar -t -f` command) and see if it contains `mainKt.class`.

Comment: Thank you thats work @k314159, thats MainKt, i think intellij default is like that